# Identify integers $1 \leq n /leq 20$ where $p_{0,0}^{(n)} > 0$ by using a transition matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

As the title says I have to answer the following: Identify integers $1 \leq n  /leq 20$ where $p_{0,0}^{(n)} > 0$ by using a transition matrix.

I know this is with the states {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7} and I have drawn my transition diagram. (linked in the comments). However I am unsure about how you go about answering the question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://ibb.co/gJDitG

Comment: $p^{(n)}(0,0) > 0 \iff$ there exists a walk of length $n$ from 0 to 0.

Comment: So does that mean n can take the value 5, 8, 13, 16?